# Yii2 how to assign widget on Html activeInput

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to assign the `Select2` widget to an `activeInput` input. My code look like so:

```
<?= Html::activeInput('text', $company, 'country_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [ some options ]) ?>
```

This throws error ofcourse which is : `PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function widget() on string'`. The explanation is poor but think the question is simple for those who know the answer :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it does not make much sense - `activeInput()` generates only input, which should be generated by widget in your case, so `activeInput()` is completely unnecessary. Just run widget directly:

```
<?= Selet2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'country_id',
])
```